# Git Error || Bug called"One or more of this task's arguments is invalid. They cannot start with '-' "

Tags: git, github, kernel, atlassian-sourcetree

I have done my development on a branch then stashed it. Then applied it to an other branch and committed it. But When I try to push my commit the error below appears. Why is that happening? Cant find any solution and I do not understand what the link below is trying to tell me.

[image: Error SS]

Comment: What command did you use exaclty?

Comment: I did it using Sourcecode desktop

Comment: Can you copy / paste the *text* of your error message ? (text is better than images) This error probably comes from a script run on your remote server, the lines above may give some indications about what the origin of the error can be.

Comment: git -c color.branch=false -c color.diff=false -c color.status=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags "https://[myUserName]: [myToken]@github.com/[myRepo]" refs/heads/develop:refs/heads/develop 
One or more of this task's arguments is invalid. They cannot start with '-', and must follow git ref-format rules: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html
Completed with errors, see above.

This is what it says

Comment: @LeGEC does that mean anything to you?

Comment: No, but perhaps someone else will know what hook or action is involved. Edit your question and paste the text there -- it will be me readable for people trying to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Update git to solve the issue.
On Mac -> brew update -> brew upgrade

Comment: It would be nice to know *why* you think this would solve the issue at hand.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it causes compatibility issues when using an old git version rather than the latest one that remote git expects.